# Mini Split with Central AC

Tags: ducts, bedroom, mini-split

Is it possible/efficient to have One mini split unit in the living room and remove all the ducts in that room to then have the central AC only cool bedrooms?

Comment: Might be efficient for that room only, but not the house.  Reducing heat gain for the house will be more efficient.

Comment: Depends on the duct layout, the specs of the A/C unit, etc.

Comment: The house is roughly 1300 sqft, 4 med/small bedrooms and an open kitchen/living room area. I was thinking of running a 24K Mini split unit in the living room/kitchen and removing those ducts to have the central ac unit cool down the rooms. Could also add attic fans to possibly reduce the heat?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't looking at ducted mini splits?

Comment: I have checked out a few options but ultimately came down to cost. Living in Florida, I am not worried about heating at all, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: if you want to keep all the rooms the same temp, then that will work fine as long as there's still good circulation. If you want the rooms hotter or colder it might be problematic because the central's return likely is in a common area, so it will mix with mini  split. If that's ok, then it basically increases your cooling capacity. If it was borderline before, that extra should make it plenty. I don't think you even need to completely close off the main area vents, and doing so may need a HVAC check/tuneup (~$125) to adjust fan speeds and timing cycles for optimum efficiency.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the input.

Comment: When you'll want heating, you'll really want heating though. Ask Texans about that. And modern Asian style wide range heat pumps would've worked great in that Texas cold snap. The problem is, the domestic makers have a near lock on the HVAC business, and they really push their clunky old "That 70's heat pump" which has poor cold performance. A couple million homes failing over to resistive heat strips at high duty cycle brought the grid to its knees.

Comment: Where is your thermostat currently located?  Usually it's in the central part of the house, and if you stop your AC from reaching that central area by closing ducts, then you loose control of your cooling moderation in areas where you do have AC ducts still open.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.

However it might also be efficient to let the mini-split be active and use fan/blower to circulate air throughout the house.  One example of this is for dehumidification.  On the old "bang-bang" A/C systems, the units have to run for a long time for dehumidification to be effective. Well if it's deep clouds (no solar gain) and 75F outside, the big system will run 2 minutes an hour, which won't dehumidify a thing.  However, if you run "blower only" to circulate air, and have only that mini-split running, it's going to run continuous at low speed, doing A/C for the whole house.  That means it will do a good job removing water.

So I would just make sure your return ducting is tip-top (so it works properly) and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion: if you already have forced air, you're probably in a great position to take advantage of a ground-source heat pump, which is even more efficient than air-sourced, and let it take over both cooling and heating tasks.